# How to make image float left while keeping position absouloute?

Tags: html, css

I centered a image perfectly horizontal in my div element like this:
[image]

Now, I need to make the image go left, but every time I try to do so the image gets out of the element.

`float: left;` does not work with `position: absolute;`, so this is what happens when I use `left: 0;`:

[image]

What CSS property can I use to fix this?

My current CSS:

```
img[id=bitcoin]{
    /* Center image */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: -25px; /* Half the height */
    margin-left: -25px; /* Half the width */
    position: absolute;

    left: 0;
}

/* Balance box */
.balance{
    height: 10%;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 30%;
    font-family: "smooth";
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px lightgray;
    display:inline-block;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: `left: 0` does it. Just remove the `margin-left` as well.

Comment: Would you mind making it a working Stack Snippet (including the relevant HTML), so we can easily reproduce the issue?

Comment: Use `transform: translate( -50%, -50% );` to center instead of negative margins. Use `#bitcoin` instead of `img[id=bitcoin]`, unless you had some pressing specificity rational going on for doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, you have used negative `margin-left`.

While using `left: 0`, please reset the `margin-left` as well:

```
margin-left: 0;
left: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code 
`margin-left: -25px; /* Half the width */`
or set value on `0`

Answer (score 0):

if you use `float:left`, you can add more with `display: table`.
Hope it can help you ^^

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `left: 50% , left: 0;` times. Maybe that's the problem?
Basically you should use -

```
position:absolute;
lift: 0;
```

And it should work.

```
img[id=bitcoin]{
    /* Center image */
    top: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: -25px; /* Half the height */
    margin-left: -25px; /* Half the width */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

/* Balance box */
.balance{
    height: 10%;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 30%;
    font-family: "smooth";
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px lightgray;
    display:inline-block;
    position: fixed;
}
```